# Where is the more reactive double bond?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I was thinking that the addition reaction would occur more easily in the double bond (marked with an arrow) where the carbons are less substituted, because they are more unstable.

[image: image 2]

Comment: You have to specify exactly what addition reaction you are talking about, see my comment on the answer. Reactivity is **not** an absolute scale as it strongly depends on the exact conditions. Compare the reactivity of C=O and C=C with $\ce{NaBH4}$ and $\ce{H2, Pd/C}$ for example

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would like to agree with you somewhat.

The stability of substituted alkenes is due to two factors:

1. Stabilizing interaction between the C=C (pi bond) (**hyperconjugation**)
2. Adjacent C-H (sigma bonds) on substituents.

The more substituents that are present in the double bond, the more hyperconjugation and the stable the alkene.

Consider the heats of of hydrogenation of these alkenes:

[image: a]

Heat of hydrogenation of alkenes is a measure of the stability of carbon-carbon double bonds.

Under similar conditions, the smaller the numerical value of heat of hydrogenation of an alkene, the **more stable** the double bond therein

To sum up,it is much is easier to create a new bond where  the bond is weak/less stable,which is the reason why alkenes (esp polysub.) easily undergo addition reactions.

**Please note that, alkenes behave as nucleophiles (Lewis bases) in polar reactions, donating a pair
of electrons from their electron-rich C=C bond to an electrophile (Lewis acid),So in this case they need stabilisation (tert. carbocation more stable)**

**Update**

Electrophilic addition of alkenes

As previosly noted alkenes behave as Lewis basis in polar reactions.

One classic example is reaction with HBr

- The reaction occurs in two steps, protonation and bromide addition,
  and involves a carbocation intermediate.
- A hydrogen atom on the electrophile HBr is attacked by  electrons from the nucleophilic double bond, forming a new C–H bond. This leaves the other carbon atom with a + charge and a vacant p orbital. Simultaneously, two electrons from the H–Br bond move onto bromine, giving bromide anion.
- The carbocation intermediate that results is itself an electrophile, which can accept an electron pair
  from nucleophilic Br- ion to form a C-Br bond and yield a neutral addition
  product.

**Markovnikov’s rule**

- In the addition of HX to an alkene, the H attaches to the carbon with
  fewer alkyl substituents and the X attaches to the carbon with more
  alkyl substituents.
- In the addition of HX to an alkene, the more highly substituted
  carbocation is formed as the intermediate rather than the less highly
  substituted one.

References

Image and some content from McMurry Organic chemistry

Comment: You don't know what addition it is, if it is polar addition of HX it is going to react on the more substituted double bond (tertiary carbocation). If it is hydroboration it is going to be less substituted (sterics), etc.

Comment: Better to ask the asker for clarification in such cases.

Comment: Sorry about that. If it is a Eletrophilic addition, then it wouldn't on the one that i pointed, right?

Comment: I'm not downvoting "just because I want to". The answer is wrong because it overgeneralises alkene reactivity.

Comment: @orthocresol, Im sure you have to answer the rest, since you brought that up. But seriously lets be FAIR!

Comment: Downvotes can be retracted easily after the post has been edited. I still think it would be good if there was a clear statement that the relative reactivity depends on the circumstances.

Comment: @xavier_fakerat Thank you for clearing that out. I really feel that i did the mistake here on not being specific, and Xavier gave the answer from what i gave. I should've be more specific, so i'll keep my upvote...